# Is there a symmetry one can impose to forbid a four point interaction term?

Tags: lagrangian-formalism, symmetry, field-theory, interactions

If I have this lagrangian of a real scalar field $S$: $$\mathcal{L}=\frac{1}{2}\partial_\mu S\partial^\mu S-\frac{\mu^2}{2}S^2-\frac{\lambda}{4!} S^4$$ does there exist a symmetry one can impose to forbid the $S^4$ term?
Now in principle I could impose a shift symmetry $S\rightarrow S+\varepsilon$, but this would also force the mass to be 0. I must admit I have no experience with shift symmetries, so is this actually legitimate?
However I would still like to keep the mass term.

Comment: How about scale symmetry?

Comment: Do you want to forbid just the S^4 term or any interaction term? If it's the latter there is an answer, if it's the former I don't think so.

Comment: @FrodCube Yes I want only to forbid the $\lambda S^4$ term and in principle also add a portal coupling $\lambda_p S^2 |H|^2$.  Now in principle I could live with an approximate symmetry, but I was wondering if there is a possibility.

Comment: @Qmechanic  So you mean $S\rightarrow e^\Lambda S$ and rescaling all dimensionfull parameters (here only $\mu^2\rightarrow e^{-2\Lambda}\mu^2$) and the derivatives accordingly? That seems legitimate to me, but can the parameters in the Lagrangian transform non-trivially if they are dimensionfull? I must admit I have never seen such a symmetry.

Comment: @krabbypatty The problem is that the $H^2 S^2$ term will induce a $S^4$ at one loop ($\lambda_s \sim \lambda_p^2/(16 \pi^2)$). You can't get rid of that without artificially tuning your parameters. There's no symmetries (exact or approximate) that can help you here.

Comment: @FrodCube You are absolutely right, but indeed this was my hope to forbid the $S^4$ at tree-level such that I can have it naturally of order $\lambda_s \sim \lambda_p^2/(16 \pi^2)$. Sorry my formulation was wrong I want to forbid $S^4$ at  tree-level such that I can have a natural parameter $\lambda_s \sim \lambda_p^2/(16 \pi^2)$. Would this be possible?